# Form submit for react-country-region-selector using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to implement country-region selection (dropdown) in ReactJS.

I have used react-country-region-selector and created a component `CountryRegion` which has the `CountryDropDown` and `RegionDropDown` implementation.

My app uses redux-form. I need to pass the user selected values for counry and region to the parent form in which I am using the `CountryRegion` component.

I tried making using of redux-form "Fields" but it throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined.

This is the CountryRegion.jsx -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'
import 'react-virtualized/styles.css'
import 'react-virtualized-select/styles.css'
import { CountryDropdown, RegionDropdown } from 'react-country-region-selector';

class CountryRegion extends Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { country: '', region: '' };
}

selectCountry (val) {
    this.setState({ country: val });
}

selectRegion (value) {
    this.setState({ region: value });
}

render () {
    const {input, name, className} = this.props;
    const {country, region } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <label className={"col-form-label"}>Work Country</label>
            <CountryDropdown class="form-control" name="COUNTRY"
                value={country}
                valueType="short" priorityOptions={["US","CA"]} showDefaultOption={false}
                             onChange={(val) => {input.onChange(this.selectCountry(val)); }}/>
            <label className={"col-form-label"}>Work State / Province</label>
            <RegionDropdown class="form-control" name="STATE"
                country={this.state.country}
                value={this.state.region}
                valueType="short"
                countryValueType="short"
                            showDefaultOption={false}
                           onChange={(value) => {input.onChange(this.selectRegion(value));}}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default CountryRegion;
```

This is how I am referring the CountryRegion code in parent form:

```
{<Fields names={[COUNTRY,STATE]} component={CountryRegion}/>}
```

How do I bind the value from the two drop downs to form attribute or Fields in redux form every time user selects or changes the dropdown values?

Comment: The parent form has below code - Fields names={[COUNTRY,STATE]} component={CountryRegion}

Comment: You forgot to pass input as a prop from parent or from container if you're using react-redux connect.

Comment: Thanks @HMR Yes, I am using redux connect. Do you have a sample code how to pass input as prop from parent to form container? I am not sure on the syntax part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used props to bind the properties for form submission. The code is below for onchange method-

```
<RegionDropdown className="form-control" name="STATE"
                            country={country}
                            value={region}
                            valueType="short"
                            countryValueType="short"
                            showDefaultOption={true}
                            defaultOptionLabel={"Select State"}
                            onChange={(value) => 
{this.props.state.input.onChange(this.selectRegion(value));}}/>
```